# oracle query Concatenate all the columns with ','

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

I am using the HR Schema and I would like to concatenate all the columns with ',' for every row.

My code is :

```
SELECT employee_id || ',' || first_name || ',' || last_name || ',' || email || ',' || phone_number || ','|| job_id || ',' || manager_id || ',' || hire_date || ','
|| salary || ',' || commission_pct || ',' || department_id

THE_OUTPUT FROM employees;
```

Is there a better way (for instance using listagg function) ?
I am thinking if the table has 1000 columns I can't do the above

Thanks a lot

Comment: You shouldn't do that in SQL. This is typically a presentation issue. Why not leave that task to the presentation layer ?

Comment: If the table has 1000 columns, you have a pretty serious design problem. Concatenating columns is not the job of the database. You should do that in your presentation logic.

Comment: No need to do anything at query level, you just need to format your output.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to concatenate all the columns with ',' for every row

Then use the **SQL*Plus** commands and generate your desired output. It is all about **formatting** the output.

- **SQL*Plus**

For example,

```
SQL> SET colsep ,
SQL> SET pagesize 20
SQL> SET trimspool ON
SQL> SET linesize 200
SQL> SELECT * FROM hr.employees WHERE ROWNUM <=10;

EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME          ,LAST_NAME                ,EMAIL                    ,PHONE_NUMBER     ,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID    ,    SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID
-----------,--------------------,-------------------------,-------------------------,--------------------,---------,----------,----------,--------------,----------,-------------
        100,Steven              ,King                     ,SKING                    ,515.123.4567        ,17-JUN-03,AD_PRES   ,     24000,              ,          ,           90
        101,Neena               ,Kochhar                  ,NKOCHHAR                 ,515.123.4568        ,21-SEP-05,AD_VP     ,     17000,              ,       100,           90
        102,Lex                 ,De Haan                  ,LDEHAAN                  ,515.123.4569        ,13-JAN-01,AD_VP     ,     17000,              ,       100,           90
        103,Alexander           ,Hunold                   ,AHUNOLD                  ,590.423.4567        ,03-JAN-06,IT_PROG   ,      9000,              ,       102,           60
        104,Bruce               ,Ernst                    ,BERNST                   ,590.423.4568        ,21-MAY-07,IT_PROG   ,      6000,              ,       103,           60
        105,David               ,Austin                   ,DAUSTIN                  ,590.423.4569        ,25-JUN-05,IT_PROG   ,      4800,              ,       103,           60
        106,Valli               ,Pataballa                ,VPATABAL                 ,590.423.4560        ,05-FEB-06,IT_PROG   ,      4800,              ,       103,           60
        107,Diana               ,Lorentz                  ,DLORENTZ                 ,590.423.5567        ,07-FEB-07,IT_PROG   ,      4200,              ,       103,           60
        108,Nancy               ,Greenberg                ,NGREENBE                 ,515.124.4569        ,17-AUG-02,FI_MGR    ,     12008,              ,       101,          100
        109,Daniel              ,Faviet                   ,DFAVIET                  ,515.124.4169        ,16-AUG-02,FI_ACCOUNT,      9000,              ,       108,          100

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

- **SQL Developer Version pre 4.1**

Alternatively, you could use the new **`/*csv*/`** **hint** in **SQL Developer**.

```
/*csv*/
```

For example, in my **SQL Developer Version 3.2.20.10**:

[image]

- **SQL Developer Version 4.1**

New in SQL Developer version 4.1, use the following just like sqlplus command and run as script. No need of the hint in the query.

```
SET SQLFORMAT csv
```