# convert Oracle .dmp file to CSV/TSV

Tags: oracle

I am wondering if there are any tools to convert Oracle .dmp file to CSV/TSV, or other kinds of text format which is easy to be parsed by Python or other script language? 
Any tool running on Windows or Linux is fine. I prefer when this tool preserves unicode characters.

Comment: The tool is called "the Oracle database". An Oracle .dmp file is a proprietary format that can only be read by Oracle and the only way to extract the data in the file is to use `impdp` (or the deprecated `imp` if the file was created with the deprecated `exp` tool).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks and impdp could only import to an Oracle DB? I want to convert to a text format other than into Oracle DB. :)

Comment: The only way is to import those files into an Oracle database and then create the text files from there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, got it. Any Oracle DB version requirements? Like the Oracle DB version must be the same as the one which export to .dmp file?

Comment: There has _recently_ been some activity around the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326712/how-to-use-oracle-dmp-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> convert Oracle .dmp file to CSV/TSV

The only way is to first import the data into the database using `IMPDP` or `IMP` depending on the database version.

For example,

```
impdp username/password@sid DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=dumpfile.dmp
```

Once your import is done, you can `SPOOL` the data as **CSV** file.

For example,

```
SET colsep ,
spool D:\test.csv
SELECT ename FROM emp;
spool off
```

There are many ways to spool the data as comma-delimited, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30907384/3989608).